# whatsapp and twitter is not getting images in android app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

i am create an app where i am sending images and vedio in social media apps facebook g+ is working proper but whatsapp and twitter is not working i am using this code

**code is for whatsapp**

```
 Button whtsapp_sahre = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.whatsapp_btn);
    whtsapp_sahre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://\" + getPackageName() + \"/drawable/pic8");
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //Target whatsapp:
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            //Add text and then Image URI
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                try{
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
            }
        }
    });
```

**and twitter code is**

```
Button _Twwiterbtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.twwiter_btn);
    _Twwiterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,R.drawable.pic8);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,"HELLO status");
            shareIntent.setType("image/*")
                    .setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            try {
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android&hl=en")));
            }
        }
    });
```

please help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code its help you first your path is may be wrong

**code for whatsapp**

```
 String imagePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/img.jpg";
  File f=new File(imagePath);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
  Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
  share.setType("image/*");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"testing text");
  share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
  share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  startActivity(share);
```

**and code for twitter**

```
      String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/img.jpg";
            File f=new File(imagePath);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello Amit Basliyal");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(share);
```

may be help you thanks